# gprof and eclipse error

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, profiling, provisioning-profile

I am trying to do this step in here

[open gmon.out file in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.linuxtools.gprof.docs%2FLinux_Tools_Project%2FGProf%2FUser_Guide%2FInstallation-and-Set-Up.html)

But the gmon.out file generated looks like that and does't open what I am doing wrong, I tried many times and restarted Eclipse , Cleaned and rebuilt. etc.. but nothing works

My code is just hello world output and it is working fine and I can see the content of the gmon.out file using the console command

```
gprof bel gmon.out > output
```

But I can't see it using Eclipse 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the latest version of Eclipse, If you are using Ubuntu and Eclipse installer didn't find oracle Java, [Try this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-oracle-java-6-7-or-8-ubuntu-14-04/)